# HTML e-mail template testing - for web and mobiles

Tags: html, templates, email, mobile

I am not sure that this is the right place for this question so if not please advice me where to ask.

I am currently building a HTML e-mail template with sophisticated design and I am wondering how & where to test it. In "how & where" I mean which are the most common mail applications for desktop and mobile devices. So is there some emulators of mobile devices where I can test how it looks. For web I am going to test Gmail and Yahoo - do I have to test something else?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth testing Hotmail too, as this often treats images differently. 
Outlook 2007/10 is a must (it doesn't show background images).

[Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/testing/) and [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/) offer testing across a wide range of desktop, web and mobile clients